# Depend on JDK 1.6 and 1.7 (x86) different GraphicsDevice

Tags: java, swing, java-8, java-7, java-6

I have issue about java  swing on multi screen. On JDK 1.6, it's work ok on duals screen. But on JDK 1.7, it has a issue : 
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

```
adding a container to a container on a different GraphicsDevice
    at java.awt.Component.checkGD(Component.java:1182)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1165)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1086)
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.addImpl(JSplitPane.java:1032)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
```

Code : it error here :

```
frameQuickPreiview.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                closeQuickPreview(false);
            }
        });
```

and Graphic in javax.swing.JplitPane is error

```
protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
        super.paintChildren(g);

        SplitPaneUI        ui = getUI();

        if (ui != null) {
            Graphics           tempG = g.create();
            ui.finishedPaintingChildren(this, tempG);
            tempG.dispose();
        }
    }
```

Can you explain how to have different ?

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I have 2 screen and 2 jframe: mainframe and preview jframe. The preview jframe inside mainframe. When I open the prevew frame, it 's outside mainframe and move this frame to scrren 2. After that, I close the preview frame. Expect result: the preview frame is inside mainframe. It's work OK on JDK 1.6, but not on JDK 1.7.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all. It's bug of JDK https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222051.